# Regular expression to replace second occurrence of dot

Tags: python, regex

String is Hello.world.hello. I wanted to replace the second occurrence of the dot with '_'.

```py
str = "Hello. world. Hello!" 
x = re.sub(r'^((.){1}).', r'\1_', str)
#x = str.find(str.find('.')
print(x)
```

The output I am getting is 'H_llo. world. Hello!'. What should be the correct solution

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```py
import re
text = "Hello. world. Hello!" 
print( re.sub(r'^([^.]*\.[^.]*)\.', r'\1_', text) )
# => Hello. world_ Hello!
```

See [the Python demo](https://ideone.com/FIZeFj) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QIaL7A/1).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `([^.]*\.[^.]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a `.`, a dot and again any 0+ non-dots
- `\.` - a dot.

The replacement is Group 1 value + `_`.

It is also possible to do without a regex:

```py
text = "Hello. world. Hello!" 
chunks = text.split('.', 2) # split the text twice
if len(chunks) > 2:         # if there are more than 2 items
    print( fr'{".".join(chunks[0:2])}_{chunks[2]}' )
else:
    print(text)             # Replace the second dot or print the original
# => Hello. world_ Hello!
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/ZaII7f).

Comment: Yeah using split() it could have been done, but i thought what could be regex for this one. Thanks for solution.

Comment: @Pratikdasbaghel Please make sure you do not name your variable as `str`, it is a Python built-in. Also, make sure to test the solution against a `text = 'Hello.\nworld. Hello\n!'` string.

Comment: You can use `text.split('.', 2)` to avoid the second `join`

Comment: Right, updated the second snippet and added comments.

Comment: @Pratikdasbaghel If my answer did not solve your problem please consider updating the question.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Written and tested in Python3.8

```
import re
str1 = "Hello. world. Hello!"
re.sub(r'^(.*?\.)([^.]*)\.(.*)$', r'\1\2_\3', str1)
'Hello. world_ Hello!'
```

***Explanation:*** Simply importing `re` function of Python3.8 then creating str1 variable with value. Then using `re.sub` function to replace 2nd dot with `_` as per requirement. In `re.sub` function on first argument giving regex to match everything apart from 2nd dot(in 3 capturing groups) and replacing them as per need with respective capturing groups placing `_` on place of 2nd dot.

***Explanation of regex:***

```
^(.*?\.)  ##Creating 1st capturing group, where Matching till 1st dot from staring of value.
([^.]*)   ##Creating 2nd capturing group, matching just before dot(2nd dot) here.
\.        ##Matching exact literal dot here.
(.*)$     ##Matching/keeping everything else till last of value in 3rd capturing group.
```